# Getting valid format xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am creating an `xml` file using python which is giving out the following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite>
      <name>ABC</name>
      <id>9022e01f-8b0c-4a47-86de-b41192116149</id>
      <tests>2048</tests>
      <failures>0</failures>
      <log> </log>
      <testcase>
         <Name>HomePage</Name>
         <Pass>420</Pass>
         <Fail>0</Fail>
         <Log> </Log>
```

Desired output is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="ABC" tests="%%%%%%%" failures="%%%%%%%%" failed="%%%%%%%"  id="39fd646d-526a-c4f4-10bb-05366a09b2ea" log="">
  
    <testcase name="TTTTTTTTTTTT" log="+ SSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTTTTT&#xD;&#xA;" />
```

This is the code I am using

```
root = ET.Element("testsuites")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "testsuite")

ET.SubElement(doc, "name").text = "ABC"
ET.SubElement(doc, "id").text = str(uuid.uuid4())
ET.SubElement(doc, "tests").text = f"{total_tests}"
ET.SubElement(doc, "failures").text = f"{failed}"
ET.SubElement(doc, "log").text = " "
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
doc2 = ET.SubElement(doc, "testcase")
for na, tot, pa, fa in zip(tcname, tctotal, tcpasses, tcfails):
    ET.SubElement(doc2, "Name").text = f"{na}"
    #ET.SubElement(doc2, "Total Tests").text = f"{tot}"
    ET.SubElement(doc2, "Pass").text = f"{pa}"
    ET.SubElement(doc2, "Fail").text = f"{fa}"
    ET.SubElement(doc2, "Log").text = " "

xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="   ")
with open("Test.xml", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)
```

How can I get the desired format?

Comment: If you don't want sub-elements, don't use `SubElement`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SubElement` convenience function accepts a dict of attributes.

```
import uuid
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("testsuites")
suite = ET.SubElement(
    root,
    "testsuite",
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
        "tests": "123",
        "failures": "456",
        "log": "",
    },
)
case = ET.SubElement(
    suite,
    "testcase",
    {
        "name": "ttt",
        "log": "lll",
    },
)

print(ET.tostring(root, "unicode"))
```

outputs (prettified here)

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="ABC" id="6eaa04eb-b915-43ba-b949-7be1f0af9d4a" tests="123" failures="456" log="">
    <testcase name="ttt" log="lll"/>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```